# tcp or udp, another comparision

Tags: c, linux, networking, network-programming

Consider a cache application with thousands of requests per second where the client asks for an object using an integer index and the server sends the object back to it. (Linux only)

What would be faster for an UDP protocol:

- Send multiple replies in a single packet?
- Send a single reply in one packet?

(applicable for both sides , server or client)

Disadvantages:

- Multiple replies per packet:

  - many memcpy()s will be needed to assemble packet with multiple replies. If a get() request returns to the client 16 byte objects, a single packet of 65535 bytes would have to memcpy() about 4000 objects before issuing sendto() system call. *memcpy() is costly*
  - An UDP packet of 65000 bytes will generate about 43 udp packet headers
        since the packet will be transmitted in fragmetns, due to 1500 default MTU size. *not a big overhead*
- Single reply per packet:

  - every get() will result in 28 bytes of protocol overhead. For an object of 16 bytes this will be costly. The throughput of objects per second will be low and *network will be saturated with packets*. For example, sending 4000 objects will generate 4000 udp packet headers, condierably more than 43 headers with multiple replies.
  - Also, too many sendto() syscalls will *increase CPU consumption* becase the kernel has to save CPU registers on each syscall.

It appears that both methods have their disadvantages and it is not clear which solution will be better, however, the clock of gigabit ethernet runs at 1GHz while the processor is for example 3 GHz also the memory
bus is much wider than the twisted pair of the ethernet interface. So, multiple replies
per packet would be better choice since the extra memcpy()s will reduce network traffic, correct?

Now, if we use TCP instead of UDP:

- Multiple replies per packet:

  - again, many memcpy()s will be needed to assemble the packet, which shouldnt be larger than 65535 and then it would be fragmented by the kernel to send it in packets of size of the MTU *not much difference as with UDP here*
- Single reply per packet:

  - Since our 16 byte objects are distributed randomly in server's memory, we will have to issue a write() syscall per object, *the same number of syscalls as with udp* single request case.
  - every get() will result in 52 bytes of overhead due to that TCP has larger header +
    we will have to another overhead of ACK packet which is abour 40 bytes. *even bigger network traffic*

Conclusion:

1. For this particular application (sending simple data chunk to the client from an index given by the client) *TCP will not perform any better than UDP*. + consider that the implementation of TCP stack is much more complicated than UDP, more instructions are executed there. **The whole point for making the protocol to run faster is to assembly UDP packets as large to the MTU as possible**.
2. The cost of adding another NIC to the system is lower than adding another CPU. It makes sense to go for lowering the number of memcpy()s but send a bunch of small UDP packets and pay extra for the overhead of each udp header on the network side (+ some little more overhead by doing many sendto() syscalls which i think will be lower than memcpy()'s overhead) because this way with one CPU could send requests over many NICs

Will greatly appreciate your comments and your experiences on the choice of protocol.

Note:
lets set aside the reliability issues and assume our networks are error free, which is
most of the time true if you wire them correctly, and if an error occurs it is certainly not the norm

Comment: My approach to this would be to keep packets under the MTU and batch a certain number of results per packet along with identifying information, i.e. 2 of 10 or some other way to make sure you haven't lost anything. Remember that UDP permits lost packets and will not retry on its own, while TCP will attempt to resend packets that are not acknowledged. Judging by your reliability statement I'm thinking you control the network and aren't crossing any third-party/internet equipment?

Comment: Even on a robust, internal network that may not have significant data "corruption" problems on UDP, it's not all that uncommon for packets to occasionally become reordered in UDP if there are multiple routes or multiple NICs on the sending or receiving end.  Ultimately, is your protocol/application robust to packet loss, corruption, and reordering?

Comment: Even if networks are error free (hah!), switches, routers , network cards, operating systems will drop packets. It does not take that big a burst of UDP packets to fill up buffers and have packet drop as a result.

Comment: well, if a packet drop occurs the client will just resend it after a timeout. but since this should never happen why bother. The best server I have in a datacenter has 5 years of uptime and only about 300 packets with error on its /sbin/ifconfig output

Comment: I have found this article http://www.multicorepacketprocessing.com/tag/udp/ that says TCP is faster than UDP but it is not correct, since with UDP you can also send packets with 15000 bytes in size and therefore number of syscalls will be the same. Interesting read though

Comment: this is also a good explanation of how UDP works in linux kernel, also it explains about UDP_CORK which could be very useful preparing udp packet with many syscalls http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~nahum/w6998/lectures/udp.ppt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few statements here which are not accurate and change the picture a bit:

1. Multiple objects do not require multiple write() system calls, you can use writev() which fits this exact need. (good for both UDP and TCP)
2. Sending a 65K byte buffer with UDP will not create multiple headers of UDP, only multiple headers of IP with a single UDP header. Furthermore, with today 1Gbit NIC/s you could use jambo frames and increase the MTU (beyond 1500) if this is for a private network.
3. For TCP, sending an object with a write()/Send() will not generate a packet necessarily, most likely it will wait until you fill up the MSS and then dispatch several objects, remember that it is a stream and it has no packet boundaries as UDP has.
4. You cannot assume reliability, order and load, making UDP harder to manage in my opinion. TCP will handle connections when servers or clients start to be overloaded with traffic. With UDP you will have to detect such cases and react.

Comment: `sendmsg()` is likely more appropriate than `writev()`, but also has an interface that supports scatter-gather.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I personally prefer the simpler calls when I have no need for the extra... just for clarity. sendmsg is very useful when control info is required, or some flags.. or when you want to specify the address on each call. But even with UDP, if control and flags are not needed per send, using a connect and then multiple writev() looks cleaner to me.

Comment: @EdwardH Thanks Edward, this is a big help. I checked sendmsg() it has iovec parameters , so I should send/recieve the whole packet in different buffers. But I would have to do this in one syscall since UDP doesn't support partial read. Yes your points are all correct and change the picture a bit, I will have to think about it, but still UDP is low on packet header, and UDP's stack is only 2187 lines of code. The battle UDP/TCP continues...